# Android - ask server for new version of app?

Tags: javascript, android, request, server

I want my app to check in background if there is a new version of the app on MY server (not play store servers). How is it possible?

I already thought maybe i could send a background request with asynctask to my server and evaluate it with some kind of server logics (javascript?)?

Answer (score 1):

Make an HTTP-Request to your server. The script at the URL it's calling should simply return the number of the new build you made. In the App you will now be able to check the answer, wich contains the build number and compare it to its own build number.

Comment: How do i pass arguments between javascript and android?

Comment: I assume you wanted to say server<->android-app ?

Comment: Yes but i thought i can code on server with javascript?

Comment: You can with node.js - but at this point this is out off topic. You got your answer, but you will have to learn yourself how to use your server^^

Answer (score 0):

Just have an simple get api for knowing the current version of your app on the server.
then find the version of your app using `BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;`
if the version code in your server is greater than this, then there is an update available

Comment: And how do i make that get api?

Comment: If you want to keep it very simple, you can just make a url on your server which returns the latest app version(or just an html even). For example. www.yourdomain.com/appversion.php(or whatever) will give you the app version. I assume you know how to do this

Comment: yes but how do i check the version then?

Comment: check where? on the device or on the backend?